# change attribute in <iframe><frameset><iframe><div> </

Tags: javascript, iframe

i have this iframe in my php page

iframe -
 html -
  frameset -
   iframe -
    iframe - 
      iframe -
       head -
        body -
         div id="change" -
          div -

all i need is to change the attribute of the 'id="change"' into visible:hidden. I want to change via javascript.

any idea?..,

tnx for the rplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frmObj = document.all.iFrameID;
  if(frmObj) {
    frmObj.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
```

Comment: Tnx that helps. but can i also apply it into a nested iframe.., i mean their is still an iframe inside an iframe.., TNX